# Customer name in creditmemo

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, invoice, pdf, creditmemo

When I click on "print" button in admin area in credit-memo, then generated PDF is not displaying customer name in shipping and billing information. It is only displaying the telephone, country, city and street.

What is the problem? How can I add it?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below path and check whether the customer name exist or not.
Login to admin => System => Configuration => Customers => Customer Configuration => Address Templates=> Pdf

Please find the below screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Yes, the customer name exists: {{var firstname}}